# What are those string "name" properties set to various objects in Qt Canvas3D code?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

See for example the second code snippet in [this Qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-framebuffer-example.html#preparing-the-framebuffer).

It does this:

```
rttFramebuffer.name = "OffscreenRenderTarget";
```

I haven't seen this in C++ OpenGL code, which means it's probably either a Canvas3D thing or a WebGL thing inherited by Canvas3D. A quick google search, however, reveals nothing on this.

Could anyone explain why it's done and what it does?

Comment: Using strings like that is very common in "dynamic" programming languages and top performance is not a concern. And no, you won't see that a lot in C or C++ because it is awfully inefficient in a fast code path. But there are some exceptions - for example gstreamer. Since it is highly dynamic and modular, enums don't make sense, instead strings are used to specify object types.

Comment: @ddriver: ["Stringly-typed"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2444303) ([<10k](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119135549/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303))

Comment: @ddriver Given that the code in question is equivalent to `QObject::setProperty("name", "OffscreenRenderTarget")`, I have no idea what you're talking about, really... A sufficiently clever runtime would look up the property only once and use `QMetaProperty::write` instead for every subsequent call; I don't recall offhand if Qt Quick in its current incarnation does that, though. This code isn't inefficient at all. It is *not* a replacement of a `GL_` enum with a string!

Comment: @KubaOber - given that the name is not necessary nor referenced anywhere else int he example, I have no idea why bother setting it in the first place. Anyway, I was generalizing, that's what must have confused you.I incorrectly assumed that setting it must be motivated by intended future use, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The object instance returned from `createFramebuffer()` is of the `Canvas3DFrameBuffer` class, inheriting `Canvas3DAbstractObject`. Every `Canvas3DAbstractObject` has a `name` property. It is equivalent to but not the same as `QObject::objectName` property. It's use is optional and up to you. The example code will work just fine without the names being set!

It most definitely is **neither**:

1. the same as QML `id`, nor
2. has any meaning in terms of a `GL_` enum, nor
3. is same as the *name* given to framebuffer targets in e.g. [`glBindFramebuffer`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindFramebuffer.xhtml).